# Page change buttons in user profile "All actions" and "Responses" tab appear in Stack Overflow orange rather than site theme color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

The page change buttons in user profile "All actions" and "Responses" tab used to appear in a theme color for the site (e.g. blue on this Meta site).

However, as of a few days ago, these are instead appearing in orange, the theme color for Stack Overflow, on all sites:

> [image: SO orange instead of Meta blue]

It looks like a recent CSS change may have broken this color. The above screenshot was taken from my Meta profile, and the highlighted color should be blue, not orange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed last week. The page change buttons in my user profile here on this site appear in the correct blue rather than orange from Stack Overflow:

> [image: Blue highlight correct]

Comment: I knew there was a meta issue posted somewhere. Sorry for letting this slip through the cracks. It's indeed been fixed!

Comment: @AaronShekey There's [this other bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345426/navigation-page-buttons-are-orange-everywhere?noredirect=1&lq=1) about orange buttons appearing in other places in the site UI, but as far as I can tell, those are also all fixed now. Can you please verify and give that a completed tag as well?