# Navigation page buttons are orange everywhere

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, navigation

On a similar note to this question: [Page change buttons in user profile "All actions" and "Responses" tab appear in Stack Overflow orange rather than site theme color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345128/345161) (which only covers two examples only on the profile page, this question mentions more places on and outside the profile page where this bug occurs).

I've noticed that whenever there are these page buttons now, for example, the profile page, /questions and tag pages they are orange.

Per the other post I'm assuming this is a bug but if it was intentional then this is a feature request to make them theme-able per site again.

Comment: Almost everywhere, here it's red: https://stackexchange.com/users/current